# Postgresql function doesn't return anything when UUID argument is used in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty new to Postgresql. The issue I'm having is that I have a function that returns a table, but when I pass an UUID which is used in the where clause, it returns nothing. The funny thing is that if I take the SQL statement inside the function and run it by itself in PgAdmin, it gives me the right result.

The function looks like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_service (
  service_id uuid ) RETURNS TABLE(id uuid,title text,description text,category text,photo_url text,address text, 
  created_by uuid,created_on timestamp,service_rating float,rating_count bigint) AS $func$
    Select
        service.id,
        service.title,
        service.description,
        service.category,
        service.photo_url,
        service.address,
        service.created_by,
        service.created_on,
        CAST(AVG(rating.rating) AS float) as service_rating,
        Count(rating.rating) as rating_count
    from service
    left join rating_service_map map
        on service.id = map.service_id
    left join rating
        on rating.id = map.rating_id
    where service.id = service_id
    group by service.id,service.title,service.description,service.category,service.photo_url,service.address,service.created_by,service.created_on;
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I have two records in my service table. The ID is of the type uuid and has a default value of uuid_generate_v4(). One of the records has an id of '2af3f03e-b2e5-44fd-89e8-3dc5fb641732'

If I run this I get no result:

```
select * from get_service('2af3f03e-b2e5-44fd-89e8-3dc5fb641732')
```

But if I run the following statement (the SQL portion of the function), then I get my right result:

```
    Select
        service.id,
        service.title,
        service.description,
        service.category,
        service.photo_url,
        service.address,
        service.created_by,
        service.created_on,
        CAST(AVG(rating.rating) AS float) as service_rating,
        Count(rating.rating) as rating_count
    from service
    left join rating_service_map map
        on service.id = map.service_id
    left join rating
        on rating.id = map.rating_id
    where service.id = '2af3f03e-b2e5-44fd-89e8-3dc5fb641732'
    group by service.id,service.title,service.description,service.category,service.photo_url,service.address,service.created_by,service.created_on;
```

I've also tried to cast the service_id (I've tried "where service.id = sevice_id::uuid" and "where service.id = CAST(service_id AS uuid)") but none of them worked.

I really appreciate it if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've been at this for a couple of hours now.

Thank you.

Comment: try `select * from get_service('2af3f03e-b2e5-44fd-89e8-3dc5fb641732'::uuid) `  PostgreSQL selects function to call based on its  signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it's because the identifier `service_id` is ambiguous, being present as both a function parameter and a column in the `map` table.

Unlike a plain query, where such ambiguity would result in an error, conflicts in SQL functions are resolved by [giving precedence to the column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS), so `service_id` in your case is actually referring to `map.service_id`.

You can either qualify it in your function body using the name of your function (i.e. `get_service.service_id`), or simply choose another name for the parameter.

Comment: Wow that was it, thank you very much. I picked a different name for the parameter as you suggested and it worked.